# Is Kerberos safe over HTTP

Tags: http, kerberos

I have this dilemma in mind. I can't find an answer with googling.

Kerberos is done in port 80. Does that mean it's send unencrypted and can be sniffed in the network?

Answer (score 0):

Kerberos authentication on HTTP will encapsulate Kerberos ticket inside a SPNEGO token and will not expose user credentials. Replay attack is stopped by authenticators. But there is a possibility to do a active MITM attack where you would prevent server from receiving captured authenticator.